# Оптимизация чтения файла

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Как оптимизировать по памяти чтения файла, чтобы можно было читать файл любого размера. При данном коде тратится 613 МБ для выполнения

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{                
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadLine());
            var x = GetData.ParseToModel(sr.ReadLine());
            Loglist.Add(x);                       
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что дело в чтении файла, а не в размере содержимого списка `Loglist`?

Comment: Думаю @Igor прав, проверьте ваш список.

Можно кстати еще посмотреть в сторону использования File.ReadLines(...) он возвращает итератор, т.е. весь файл в память загружаться не будет(в принципе как и вас), но и код в том же foreach  будет выглядеть лаконичнее.
Но проблема с заполнением листа все равно не решается:)

Comment: Не понятно, что вы потом делаете с этим Loglist. Именно от этого зависит можно ли оптимизировать.